# Why is this simple android app recursive?

Tags: java, android, recursion, android-edittext, textview

New SO user here and fairly new to Java.  Upon running this, it crashes with a java.lang.stackoverflow error.  I'm fairly certain it is recursive but I can't figure out why.  I've tried stepping through debugging but I get an error that it can't find the class file.  Here is the code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    newPrice.addTextChangedListener(tradeWatch);
    tradeIn.addTextChangedListener(tradeWatch);
    acc.addTextChangedListener(tradeWatch);
    tradeDif.addTextChangedListener(tradeWatch);

}

TextWatcher tradeWatch = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        calcTrade();

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};

private void calcTrade() {
Editable eValue1 = newPrice.getText(), eValue2 = tradeIn.getText(), eValue3 = acc.getText();
Double value1 = 0.0, value2 = 0.0, value3 = 0.0, result = 0.0;

if (eValue1 != null)
    value1 = toDouble(eValue1);
if (eValue2 != null)
    value2 = toDouble(eValue2);
if (eValue3 != null)
    value3 = toDouble(eValue3);
if (value1 != null && value2 != null && value3 != null)
    result = value1 - (value2 + value3);
    tradeDif.setText(result.toString());

}
private double toDouble(final Editable editable) {
    final String content = editable.toString();
    if (content.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return Double.parseDouble(content);
}

public void nextPage(View v) {
    Intent i=new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    startActivity(i);
}


}
```

Comment: Your `TextWatcher` calls `calcTrade()`, which sets the text, which invokes the `TextWatcher`.

Comment: why `tradeDif.addTextChangedListener(tradeWatch);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `tradeDif` is using your `tradeWatch` TextWatcher. In that TextWatcher's `afterTextChanged()`, you call `calcTrade()`, which calls `tradeDif.setText(result.toString());`.

After Android finishes setting the text on `tradeDif`, it will again call `afterTextChanged()` on your TextWatcher, and it will continue doing so until you stop setting `tradeDif`'s text.

Comment: How could I fix this? The problem is that the editText 'tradeDif' will also be further used for more calculations just like this.  For example, this part calculates the difference, but I also want to be able to use 'tradeDif' to calculate beyond this point, using a similar technique.

Comment: Without more knowledge of how your app works and the general flow of how you expect a user to use your app, it is difficult to say. One solution would be to make `tradeDif` a non-editable TextView instead of an EditText, and potentially use a different field later. Alternatively, you could put in a flag such as `hasCalculatedDiff` before you attempt to calculate and set `tradeDif` again.

Comment: Thank you for your time.  Although it was a dumb question that I should have spotted, I wish I didn't get downvoted for it.  I want to be able to add rep to people that are willing to help.  If I get enough rep to give rep to others I'll return and add rep.

Answer (score 9):

Problem is line:

```
tradeDif.setText(result.toString());
```

You change text and it causes to call

```
afterTextChanged(Editable s)
```

again and again.

## Simple solution

1. Remove listener
2. Change value
3. Add listener